# Proper database structure for a Recipe program

Tags: mysql, database

http://stoccey.net/demo/images/templ.jpg

Hello, the link is the layout of the interface I am planning to make my program. And I came up with this database structure:

http://stoccey.net/demo/images/db%20stoccey.png

I just wanted to ask if what I did was right based on the db scheme I made.

I would appreciate your opinions. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Didn't you miss amount of ingredient per recipe?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Coupla thoughts ...

1. Recipe_item and Recipe tables can probably be the same thing ... drop Recipe, rename Recipe_item to Recipe, then rename rcpd_id to recipe_id (cleaner, IMO).
2. In Ingredients, replace ingr_id with recipe_id
3. Remove all rcpd_id fields in all tables (recipe_id is enough)
4. Ingredients and Recipe_directions tables could benefit from a "position" field, allowing them to be sorted manually or via CMS.
5. Remove rcp_id from Menu, add Menu_id to Recipe

Comment: hi neokio, what do you mean by the "position" field?

Comment: @Jag: he meant that probably you'd want to place ingredients in some specific order, maintained by that additional field

Comment: ah, like group them or what? Sorry, I'm still trying to learn things

Comment: hey @neokio, if I would do your suggestion, will my database still be normalized?

Comment: here is the db scheme I did according to your suggestions: http://stoccey.net/demo/images/stoc.png

Comment: yep that's looking pretty tight, and very normalized (zero redundancy). still think you'd benefit from adding "position" to most tables, so you can have your instructions sorted manually instead of only by the order in which they were added.

Comment: can you elaborate more on what do you mean by position because I don't really understand it. Please?

Comment: In a recipe you perform tasks in a specfic order. First add flour, then stir, order is important...

Comment: sure... in http://stoccey.net/demo/images/templ.jpg for example, "Directions to make". Say you begin adding directions, one by one. Then you suddenly remember you wanted the first direction to be "Skin and de-bone the Yak completely". Without a "position" field, adding it afterwards would put that direction at the end. By adding a "position" field (say, below the "direction" field in Recipe_directions), you could set the position manually, and do a MySQL "SELECT * FROM `Recipe_directions` WHERE `recipe_id` = '1234' ORDER BY `position` ASC" to get the directions in the correct order.

Comment: yeah. i got it now. thanks a lot neokio for making it clear. I would just like to ask another. Kindly take a look http://stoccey.net/demo/images/dedundant.jpg

The water as ingredient is duplicated? Am i getting this right?

Comment: Correct, unless you add a "Recipe_ingredients" table to match recipes to ingredients. I would only recommend this if you need to change an ingredient price and have that reflected throughout the system. In this case, ingredients would only ever have one "water" record, and the recipe_ingredients table would contain "ri_id, recipe_id, ingredient_id" and maybe a "qty" field so you could calculate costs, control inventory, etc.

Comment: That would be a better one, I would make another table named recipe_ingredients then connect ingredients and recipe tables through that so that values would wont be duplicated. Check this out >> http://stoccey.net/demo/images/db_lst.png

Is this better?

Thanks Neokio.

Comment: Thank you, thank you for the great help neokio. I would click the check mark then.